# Codeigniter - input post method is removing or emptying the post data from multi select field

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

> I am using Codeigniter 3.0.0 version

When trying access the value of a multi select drop down field named as `subjecID[ ]` using `$this->input->post()` method,it returning empty value. But When I am accessing the `$_POST['subjectID']` I can see the value in the form of an array from the `subjecID[ ]` field. Even In older version of Codeigniter I was able to get the data as an array from the post. So, what might be the issue. Please tell me if is there any configurations to change?

Below is my controller function.

```
protected function rules() {
    $rules = array(
        array(
            'field' => 'name',
            'label' => $this->lang->line("teacher_name"),
            'rules' => 'trim|required|max_length[60]'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'subjectID',
            'label' => $this->lang->line("select_subject"),
            'rules' => 'required'
        )
    );
    return $rules;
}

public function add() {
            $this->data['subjects'] = $this->subject_create_m->get_subject();
    if($_POST) {
        $rules = $this->rules();
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->data['form_validation'] = validation_errors();
            $this->data["subview"] = "teacher/add";
            $this->load->view('_layout_main', $this->data);
        } else {
            $array = array();
            $array['name'] = $this->input->post("name");
            $array['specialization'] = serialize($this->input->post('subjectID[]'));
            print_r($array);
        }
    } else {
        $this->data["subview"] = "teacher/add";
        $this->load->view('_layout_main', $this->data);
    }

}
```

Below is the Output I am getting by printing the post using the following code

```
print_r($this->input->post(NULL, FALSE));
```

`Array ( [name] => sfgfdsgfsd [subjectID] => )`

Because of this issue every time the validation is failing.

Comment: try this `$this->input->post('subjects')`

Comment: Can you please show me your controller?

Comment: no change until 3.1.7 in this scope, you still can do that with `$this->input->post('subjects')`

Comment: try this 'field' => 'subjectID[]' instead of 'field' => 'subjectID' in the validation rules

Comment: is some kind of filtering causing this issue?

Comment: Thanks a lot Abdul. It's working.

Comment: Did they change the usage or syntax of rules in 3.x?

Comment: They didn't change the Syntax of rules, actually in your case subjectID is not a single value it is an array, that's why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this `'field' => 'subjectID[]'` instead of `'field' => 'subjectID'` in the validation rules

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$this->input->post('subjects[]');
```

check helper in configuration

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('form');
```

Comment: please confirm drop down name "subjects[ ]" in view page

Answer (score 0):

i have just recently use multiple input type array its working 
use $this->input->post('subjects');

Comment: Yes, I have been accessing like that only for long time when the application is running on 2.X but When I upgraded to framework to 3.0.0 version I am facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can get array of selected values using

```
$this->input->post('subjects');
```

Or you use php post variable to get data

```
if(isset($_POST[subjects])){
foreach($_POST[subjects]) as $subject){

}
}
```

Best is post your form html code here so that proper answer can be posted

Answer (score 0):

use var_dump($this->input->post())
Or 
Did you remove index.php from url